# QGIS DB-Manager Virtual Layers geometry column not showing

Tags: qgis, dbmanager

Whenever I run a query on project layers that should return a geometry column such as

```
select 1 as id, st_union(geometry) as geometry from layer
```

the column containing the geometry simply doesn't show up. This is annoying since I can't load the results as virtual layers anymore. Using spatial functions that don't return a geometry object such as st_area do work though.
This only affects Virtual Layers in the DB-Manager no matter the data source (json,gpkg..). QGIS Versions used: 3.20.2, uninstalled then 3.20.3 on Win 10.

Could it be some setting I am overlooking or is there a easy solution?

**Update 1:** The problem appears also in the LTR-version 3.16.11 using the installer that uses 'OSGeo4W v2' but it does not appear in the same LTR-version that uses the old OSGeo4W.

**Update 2:** The problem still persists in **any qgis version that depends on OSGeo4W v2** Tried on different windows 10 machines (1609, 1809 and 21H1)
Please push this issue on the [QGIS bug tracker](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46025).

**Update 3:** Issue still persists in 3.22.3. A feasible workaround is posted [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46116#issuecomment-1022020304).
**Update 4** Issue still persists in 3.24 RC

Comment: Are you sure the geometry field is named 'geometry' and not 'geom' ? That's what the default gpkg geometri fields are named in my system.

Comment: @Encomium yes 'geometry' is the default name for virtual layers.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I guess one fix would be to include the virtual layer SQL definition as a CTE in the DB Manager query rather than looping the virtual layer in by name. But maybe that's not an option for your use case.

Comment: I've never had this issue and I've been using virtual layers regularly since 2.18. Is the geometry in your original layer valid? Which other functions have you tried apart from st_union? Do you have the same problem with points, lines and polygons (and/or multigeometry versions of each)? Do you recall which version it last worked on?

Comment: @she_weeds no matter the geometry type nor if it's valid. tried on a different win10 machine with 3.20.1. same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The missing geometry column after the switch to OSGeo4W v2 being a bug was confirmed on March 18th and fixed thanks to jef-n. Starting with QGIS 3.30.1 virtual layer geometry column in DB-Manager works again.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce. Work fine on my QGIS versions (3.16 and 3.18). You may adopt vrt file by putting the following content in a `demo.vrt` and open it as a vector layer (quite long to show)

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="bbox_from_csv_coords">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">/vsicurl/https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/raw/master/geojson/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.geojson</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL dialect="SQlite">SELECT 1 as id, ST_Union(geometry) as geometry FROM ne_10m_admin_0_countries</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Clearly, it does not solve your issue but at least, it may help to achieve your goal.

Comment: What OS are you using QGIS 3.16 and 3.18 on? If it is MS Windows, what installer did you use to install QGIS, the v1/exe or the v2/msi installer?